# Making multiple moving images respond to taps

Tags: iphone, objective-c, ios, ios5, core-graphics

In the app, I have several images (same shape and size, different colors) that move on the perimeter of a circle, kinda like cursors acting as compass needles. I want to be able to tap each of these and then display a message based on which one is tapped, but am not sure what kind of approach would be good for this. Right now I'm trying making them in to UIButtons, but it's giving me a lot of hassle. Is there a way to do this with a UITapGestureRecognizer? I doubt it's possible to have one of those on the screen, but have it keep track of 6 different moving areas and let other tap events through, and I don't think adding 6 different recognizers is a good idea, so I'm just wondering if anyone has suggestions on how to go about this. I'm using Core Graphics.

Answer (score 0):

The best method to achieve this effect would probably be to subclass a UIButton (or even UIControl if you'd like) that has the method that overrides touch.  For example if you were to subclass UIControl you could override the method below to detect touches and do what you wish with them:

```
-(BOOL)beginTrackingWithTouch:(UITouch *)touch withEvent:(UIEvent *)event
```

Then whatever you want it to look like could be done in the drawRect: method by overriding that (and uncommenting it).  Same goes for subclassing anything and tracking touches within the subclass: UIButton, UIImageView, UIControl, etc.